# Rounding of nearest 0.5

Tags: c#, rounding

I want to be rounded off this way

```
13.1, round to 13.5
13.2, round to 13.5
13.3, round to 13.5
13.4, round to 13.5
13.5 = 13.5
13.6, round to 14.0
13.7, round to 14.0
13.8, round to 14.0
13.9, round to 14.0
```

sorry for modification i need in the above way... did this way but not appropriate

```
doubleValue = Math.Round((doubleValue * 2), MidpointRounding.ToEven) / 2;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it is required for `13.1, round to 13.5` and `13.9, round to 14.0`, then:

```
double a = 13.1;
double rounded = Math.Ceil(a * 2) / 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

This works, I just tested it;

```
double a = 13.3;
var rn  =  a % 0.5 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
Math.Round(a, rn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nearest `0.5` for `13.6` and `13.7` is `13.5`, so you have correct solution.

for yours table of values:

```
var value = 13.5;
var reminder = value % (int)value;
var isMiddle = Math.Abs(reminder - 0.5) < 0.001;
var result =  (isMiddle ? Math.Round(value * 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero): Math.Round(value)*2)/ 2;
```

Comment: But i Need if is above or  13.6 it should be rounded to next number 14.0

Comment: Ok, if you will have *13.58* how it should be rounded?

Comment: 13.1, round to 13.5 13.2, round to 13.5 13.3, round to 13.5 13.4, round to 13.5 13.5 = 13.5 13.6, round to 14.0 13.7, round to 14.0 13.8, round to 14.0 13.9, round to 14.0 and i have only one decimal

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of doing this without the builtin method of c# (if you want )
its writen i c++ (I once lacked the round function in c++ )
 but you can easly change it to c# syntax

```
int round(float nNumToRound)
{

// Variable definition
int nResult;

// Check if the number is negetive
if (nNumToRound > 0)
{
    // its positive, use floor.
    nResult = floor(nNumToRound + 0.5);
}
else if (nNumToRound < 0)
{
    // its negtive, use ceil 
    nResult = ceil(nNumToRound - 0.5);
}

return (nResult);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
num = (num % 0.5 == 0 ? num : Math.Round(num));
```

works well for you solution heres the complete console program

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double[] a = new double[]{
                13.1,13.2,13.3D,13.4,13.5,13.6,13.7,13.8,13.9,13.58,13.49,13.55,
            };
            foreach (var b in a)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}",b,b % 0.5 == 0 ? b : Math.Round(b));
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

you simply would need to change `0.5` to some other number if the rounding requirement changes in future

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is proper way, but it works. Try this if you want:

```
        double doubleValue = 13.5;
        double roundedValue = 0.0;
        if (doubleValue.ToString().Contains('.'))
        {
            string s = doubleValue.ToString().Substring(doubleValue.ToString().IndexOf('.') + 1);
            if (Convert.ToInt32(s) == 5)
            {
                roundedValue = doubleValue;
            }
            else
            {
                roundedValue = Math.Round(doubleValue);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Result:      {0}", roundedValue);
```

Comment: It was the worst way of finding remainder. What did I do? :). I wanted to answer quickly I think that was the reason

Answer (score -1):

```
var a = d == (((int)d)+0.5) ? d : Math.Round(d);
```

d is a double.

Comment: Very bad solution. What if the number will be 14.5 and not 13.5 as in OP's example??

Comment: how can you keep 13.5 as constant